# Multi-level approval workflow

Tags: 2007, workflow, design, sharepoint-designer

I have a requirement to design a multi level approval workflow using SPD 2007. The workflow has three levels of approval. If the 1st or 2nd or 3rd level of approvers rejects the task it should go back to the previous level of user to continue with the same workflow instance. The workflow should not stop since when the InfoPath form is updated in the Forms library, a new WF instance will be created if there is no active task on that workflow. Has anyone worked on a similar requirement? If yes, please let me know.

Also, let me know if it is possible to move back and forth between workflow steps in an approval workflow using SPD 2007. Is it possible to use any custom actions to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the SharePoint Designer 2007 workflows are sequential which means you cannot repeat steps.  Your two options are to either instantiate an instance of the workflow for each pass forward, or to try and duplicate the steps which is a really bad idea and should only be used in very specific and simple situations.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with Visual studio for this. I did a similar workflow that looped throught x amount of approval and it worked great with VS2008. Previously another developper worked with the designer and he stopped when he encountered the problem mentionned by Mike Oryszak.